# Find out when full calendar loaded events

Tags: fullcalendar

I have a fullCalendar widget created somewhere. I cannot change the code that initialize it. So I cannot add any callbacks in the first call.

Anything like this:

```
$(elem).fullCalendar({
   complete: function () {
     ...
   }
})
```

Actually creates a new fullCalendar instead of modifying the actual fullCalendar to change/add the complete callback.

Is there an other way to find out when events are loaded I was thinking about polling `clientEvents` but I realize that I could have no events in one month so I cannot expect the array to always have something in it.

By the way, it's fullCalendar 1.6.

Answer (score 2):

You can define callbacks after the calendar object has been initialized, and to determine when all events have been rendered, use the eventAfterAllRender event. Here's how:

```
var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getCalendar');
calendar.on('eventAfterAllRender', function(view) {
    alert('all events rendered!');
});
```

Nevermind, this feature is only available starting in version 2.4.

Instead, you could poll the DOM for fullcalendar element existence, like this:

```
function checkForInit() {
    if($(".fc-view").children().length) {
        alert("initialized!");
    } else {
        setTimeout(function() {
            checkForInit();
        }, 10);
    }
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    checkForInit();
});
```

Comment: Except that as I said, it's not certain that during that time range, some events will be loaded.. So I cannot just check for fullCalendar being initialized. What will happen is that if there are no events, the loading will poll forever which would fail in some ways.

Comment: The code above doesn't poll for event elements. It polls for the table element that wraps the events, which exists regardless of whether or not there are any events for that view.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [eventAfterAllRender](https://fullcalendar.io/docs1/event_rendering/eventAfterAllRender/) event, available from version 1.6:

```
$(elem).fullCalendar({
   eventAfterAllRender: function (view) {
     ...
   }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found a solution that seems to be working!

```
var waitPrint = true

function autoPrint() {
  var elem = $('.fc')
  var calendar = elem.data('fullCalendar')
  console.log('Searching calendar')
  if (calendar && waitPrint) {
      waitPrint = false
      console.log('Bund new event')
      var _super = calendar.options.eventAfterAllRender
      calendar.options.eventAfterAllRender = function (event, element, view) {
        if (_super) {
          _super.apply(this, arguments)
        }

        window.print()
      }
  } else if (waitPrint) {
    setTimeout(autoPrint, 100)
  }
}

autoPrint()
```

Here I'm polling for an element with the `fc` class. As soon as I find one, I check for the existence of the "data" named `fullCalendar`. If it returns a dict, then it means that the fullCalendar instance has been created. This is pretty much what Dane proposed for version 2.4 but this in 1.6 there is no getter. We have to get it ourselves. Luckily, it's stored in the `data` of the element and not in some other cryptic places.

Move on to the next step, fullCalendar isn't an eventEmitter in 1.x, but we still have access to options which seems to be just a reference to the options that were passed at first. I override the `eventAfterAllRender`. Call the method that was already defined if present and call my print method when it's done.

Technically from there, we can override almost any defined method from there. The only problem is that you have to do it faster than fullCalendar get initialized.

I believe that if we dig deeper, we could potentially patch the calendar library directly to remove the timing issues. Polling isn't very great.

**Best Solution So far**

```
var oldFullCalendar = $.fn.fullCalendar
function newFull(options) {
  var _super_func = null

  if (typeof options == 'string') {
    oldFullCalendar.apply(this, arguments)
  } else {
    options = options || {}
    if (options.loading) {
      _super_func = options.loading
    }
    options.loading = function (loading) {
      console.log(loading, 'loading')

      if (_super_func) {
        _super_func.apply(this, arguments) 
      }
      if (!loading) {
        window.print()
      }
    }

    oldFullCalendar.apply(this, arguments)
  }
}
$.fn.fullCalendar = newFull
```

The first solution could probably be improved by overriding `loading` instead. Since it's the method that notify when loading has been processed and which is also apparently called after the `eventAfterAllRender` callback.